# TEA Algorithm java implementation and the issue of 32 unsigned bits

Tags: java, algorithm, security, encryption, unsigned

I am trying to implement the Tiny Encryption Algorithm (TEA) in java. Since the algorithm divides each 64 bit block into left and right sub-blocks, where each sub-block is 32 unsigned integer according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm) source.

As expected, I faced the issue of java not supporting unsigned 32 bit integer. I was getting errors about the number Format everywhere.

So I decided to use BigInteger, which introduced a new problem to me. Based on my understanding, since TEA uses shifting and addition of 32 bits integers, It is supposed to keep the result of these operation in 32 bits, so that the ciphertext will also be 32 bits per sub-block. However, with shifting and addition, BigInteger did not keep 32 bits per sub-block. Indeed, I got unexpectedly a very large number of bits as a ciphertext output.

So I decided to keep the BigInteger, while implementing the shift, addition, and subtraction in separate methods. Unfortunately, I am not getting correct results. As illustrated below, the decrypted ciphertext does not equal the original plaintext. What is the solution to my problem? I am getting the following output:

```
Original Plain Text:0x0123456789ABCDEF
CipherText:0xa0761126d09724fd
Decrypted CipherText is:0x8d5a4a234b3c6720
```

Below is my code.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;


public class TEA {

    BigInteger [] K ; //128 bits key
    private String plainText;
    public static final BigInteger delta = new BigInteger("9e3779b9",16);


    //constructor receives a string of plaintext and 128 bit key in hexadecimal
    public TEA(String plainText, String key)
    {
        parseKey(key);


    }

    //constructor receives a hexadecimal 
    public TEA(String key)
    {

        parseKey(key);

    }

    //parses a 128 bit key, given in hexadecimal form, and store its value in 4 integers (total of 128 bits), 
    private void parseKey(String key)
    {
        if(key.substring(0,2).equals("0x"))
            key= key.substring(2);

        //validating input
        if(key.length() != 32)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid key size!");
            return;
        }


        //dividing the key into 4 strings
        String[] kStr = new String[4];
        int index=-1;
        for(int i=0; i<key.length(); i++)
        {
            if(i%8 == 0)
            {
                index++;
                kStr[index]="";

            }
            kStr[index] = kStr[index] + key.charAt(i);
        }


        //converting the 4 hex strings into 4 integers
        K= new BigInteger[4];
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
            K[i] = new BigInteger(kStr[i], 16); 

    }

    //receives a plaintext block of 64 bits in hexadecimal to be encrypted
    //returns the cipher block
    String encryptBlock(String plainTextBlock)
    {
        if(plainTextBlock.substring(0,2).equals("0x"))
            plainTextBlock= plainTextBlock.substring(2);

        //validating input
        if(plainTextBlock.length()!=16)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid block size!");
            return null;

        }

        //separating the string block into left and right blocks
        String LStr = plainTextBlock.substring(0, 8); //left block (32 bit)
        String RStr = plainTextBlock.substring(8); //right block (32 bit)

        //converting left and right blocks to integers
        BigInteger L = new BigInteger(LStr, 16);
        BigInteger R = new BigInteger(RStr, 16);


        BigInteger sum= new BigInteger("0");
        //32 rounds
        for(int i=0; i<32; i++)
        {
            sum = sum.add(delta);
            L= sum(L,  (sum(shiftLeft(R,4),K[0]))   .xor(sum(R,sum))    .xor(sum(shiftRight(R,5),K[1]))) ;
            R= sum(R,  (sum(shiftLeft(L,4),K[2]))   .xor(sum(L,sum))    .xor(sum(shiftRight(L,5),K[3]))) ;

            //R= R.add(  (shiftLeft(R,4).add(K[2])).xor(L.add(sum)).xor(shiftRight(L,5).add(K[3])) );


        }

        //joining back the blocks as hex
        String cipherBlock = "0x"+L.toString(16)+R.toString(16)+"";


        return cipherBlock;
    }


    //receives a ciphertext block of 64 bits in hexadecimal to be decrypted
    //returns the plaintext block
    String decryptBlock(String cipherBlock)
    {
        if(cipherBlock.substring(0,2).equals("0x"))
            cipherBlock= cipherBlock.substring(2);

        //validating input
        if(cipherBlock.length()!=16)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid block size!");
            return null;

        }

        //separating the string block into left and right blocks
        String LStr = cipherBlock.substring(0, 8); //left block (32 bit)
        String RStr = cipherBlock.substring(8); //right block (32 bit)

        //converting left and right blocks to integers
        BigInteger L = new BigInteger(LStr, 16);
        BigInteger R = new BigInteger(RStr, 16);

        BigInteger sum= shiftLeft(delta,5);
        //32 rounds
        for(int i=0; i<32; i++)
        {

            R= subtract(R,  (sum(shiftLeft(L,4),K[2]))   .xor(sum(L,sum))    .xor(sum(shiftRight(L,5),K[3]))) ;
            L= subtract(L,  (sum(shiftLeft(R,4),K[0]))   .xor(sum(R,sum))    .xor(sum(shiftRight(R,5),K[1]))) ;


            //R= R.subtract(  (L.shiftLeft(4).add(K[2])).xor(L.add(sum)).xor(L.shiftRight(5).add(K[3])) );
            //L= L.subtract(  (R.shiftLeft(4).add(K[0])).xor(R.add(sum)).xor(R.shiftRight(5).add(K[1])) );
            sum = sum.subtract(delta);  
        }

        //joining back the blocks as hex
        String plainTextBlock = "0x"+L.toString(16)+R.toString(16)+"";


        return plainTextBlock;
    }


    private BigInteger shiftLeft(BigInteger x, int steps)
    {

       BigInteger shifted=null;
       boolean negative =false;

       String xStr = x.toString(2);

       //removing negative sign while shifting (currently)
       if(xStr.charAt(0)=='-')
       {
           negative= true;
           xStr = xStr.substring(1);
       }


       int additionalSize = 32- xStr.length();

       for(int i=0; i<additionalSize; i++)
           xStr= "0"+xStr;



       for(int i=0; i<steps; i++)
       {
           xStr = xStr.substring(1);
           xStr = xStr+"0";
       }

       //one last addition of negative sign if the number is negative
       if(negative==true)
           xStr= "-"+xStr;

       //System.out.println(xStr);
      shifted = new BigInteger(xStr,2);

        return shifted;
    }


    private BigInteger shiftRight(BigInteger x, int steps)
    {
       BigInteger shifted=null;
       boolean negative = false;

       String xStr = x.toString(2);

       //removing negative sign while shifting (currently)
       if(xStr.charAt(0)=='-')
       {
           negative= true;
           xStr = xStr.substring(1);
       }

       int additionalSize = 32- xStr.length();

       for(int i=0; i<additionalSize; i++)
           xStr= "0"+xStr;


       for(int i=0; i<steps; i++)
       {
           xStr = xStr.substring(0,xStr.length()-1);
           xStr = "0"+xStr;
       }

       //one last addition of negative sign if the number is negative
       if(negative==true)
           xStr= "-"+xStr;

      shifted = new BigInteger(xStr,2);

        return shifted;
    }

    private BigInteger sum(BigInteger a, BigInteger b)
    {

        BigInteger sum = a.add(b);
        String sumStr = sum.toString(2);
        if(sumStr.length()>32)
        {
            int diff = sumStr.length()- 32;
            sumStr = sumStr.substring(diff);
        }

        BigInteger newSum = new BigInteger(sumStr,2);

        return newSum;
    }

    private BigInteger subtract(BigInteger a, BigInteger b)
    {

        BigInteger sub = a.subtract(b);

        String subStr = sub.toString(2);
        if(subStr.length()>32)
        {
            int diff = subStr.length()- 32;
            subStr = subStr.substring(diff);
        }

        BigInteger newSub = new BigInteger(subStr,2);

        return newSub;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        String plainText="0x0123456789ABCDEF";
        String key= "0xA56BABCD00000000FFFFFFFFABCDEF01";
        TEA tea = new TEA(key);
        String cipherText = tea.encryptBlock(plainText);
        System.out.println("Original Plain Text:"+plainText);
        System.out.println("CipherText:"+cipherText);
        System.out.println("Decrypted CipherText is:"+tea.decryptBlock(cipherText));




    }


}
```

Comment: To truncate the left shifts at 32 bits, AND the result of the shift with 0xffffffff

Comment: Should I do that with BigInteger or you mean with the primitive type int?

Comment: How about the addition and subtraction overflow?

Comment: What @WDS probably means is that you can create a BigInteger mask of 0xffffffff at the beginning and ANDing the result of at-risk operations such as left shift with that mask.

Comment: Yep, @ArtjomB. is right.  I've written implementations of a couple different crypto algorithms just to help myself learn how they work, just like you're doing with TEA here.  And I've had to do exactly what I suggested you do, using the 0xFFFFFFFF mask to keep the 32 least significant bits as they are and discard the rest.  Apply this mask after any at-risk operation as Artjom B. mentioned.  You could instead calculate those operations modulo 2^32, but I suspect the bitwise operation is faster.

Comment: You guys are my HEROS!

Comment: I doubt you need to use BigInteger. The fact that java ints are signed is most likely of no consequence when adding or subtracting 32-bit integers, due to Java's rules for handling overflow. I'm not familiar with TEA but I see nothing in the article you link to that requires and special handling of Java ints.

Answer (score 2):

I saw no reason to use BigIntegers, so I tried my own implementation in Java that is almost a verbatim copy of the C code in the wikipedia article. It looks correct to me, though I don't have tests to run against it.

```
public class TEAToy {

    private final static int DELTA = 0x9e3779b9;
    private final static int DECRYPT_SUM_INIT = 0xC6EF3720;
    private final static long MASK32 = (1L << 32) - 1;
    public static long encrypt(long in, int [] k) {
        int v1 = (int) in;
        int v0 = (int) (in >>> 32);
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<32; i++) {
            sum += DELTA;
            v0 += ((v1<<4) + k[0]) ^ (v1 + sum) ^ ((v1>>>5) + k[1]);
            v1 += ((v0<<4) + k[2]) ^ (v0 + sum) ^ ((v0>>>5) + k[3]);
        }

        return (v0 & MASK32) << 32 | (v1 & MASK32);

    }

    public static long decrypt(long in, int [] k) {
        int v1 = (int) in;
        int v0 = (int) (in >>> 32);
        int sum = DECRYPT_SUM_INIT;
        for (int i=0; i<32; i++) {
            v1 -= ((v0<<4) + k[2]) ^ (v0 + sum) ^ ((v0>>>5) + k[3]);
            v0 -= ((v1<<4) + k[0]) ^ (v1 + sum) ^ ((v1>>>5) + k[1]);
            sum -= DELTA;
        }
        return (v0 & MASK32) << 32 | (v1 & MASK32);
    }
```

As you can see, the fact the Java's ints are signed makes very little difference.